# Trying to add a class to a div based on its assigned jQuery index number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I append a series of divs to my $board parent using the following:

```
    var $board = $('<div id="board"></div>');
    var $row = $('<div class="row"></div>');
    var $cell = $('<div class="box stdBG"></div>')
    var $aRow;
    var $aCell;
    for (var i=0; i < 17; i++){
        $aRow = $row.clone();
        $board.append($aRow);
        for (var j =0; j <25; j++){
            $aCell = $cell.clone();
            $aRow.append($aCell); 
            if (i===8 && j==12){
                $aCell.removeClass('stdBG').addClass('marvin');
                indexI = i;
                indexJ = j;
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine but then I try to add the 'marvin' class to an adjacent div using:

```
    indexJ += 1;
    $('.row').eq(indexI).find('.cell').eq(indexJ).addClass('marvin');
```

it doesn't do anything and I don't get any error messages. This rookie needs help!

Comment: Where is the position of `indexJ += 1; ...` section in your mentioned main code?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Mehdi, the "for" loop is the totality of a called function. indexI and indexJ are initialized at the top of my script file, and the indexJ += 1 is directly above the $('.row') as above, and part of a separate function. My console.logs of the indexI/J's give me the correct values; they just don't seem to get applied by the $('.row') line

Comment: If you are trying to add a class to something that was added dynamically you should target the find to something that was initially in the dom. Like body or another container div.

Comment: Hard for anyone to help when we can't see the associated html and can't reproduce the problem due to lack of code . As previously mentioned provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks all, will work on whittling down my problem code to something manageable tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you're looking for `.cell` class which does not exist. It must have been `.box`.

> $('.row').eq(indexI).find('**.cell**').eq(indexJ).addClass('marvin');

I've made this snippet and it works fine:

```js
var indexI = 0,
  indexJ = 0;

var $board = $('#board');
var $row = $('<div class="row"></div>');
var $cell = $('<div class="box stdBG"></div>');

for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
  var $aRow = $row.clone();
  $board.append($aRow);
  for (var j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
    var $aCell = $cell.clone();
    $aRow.append($aCell);
    if (i === 8 && j === 12) {
      $aCell.removeClass('stdBG').addClass('marvin');
      indexI = i;
      indexJ = j;
    }
  }
}

indexJ += 1;
$('.row').eq(indexI).find('.box').eq(indexJ).addClass('marvin');
```

```css
div {
  line-height: 0
}

.box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #fff
}

.stdBG {
  background: grey
}

.marvin {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just whittled down a small test case myself and finally saw that I'd never changed box to cell:

Comment: Nothing like my first post here being over something stupid, but live and learn. Thanks again all...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
.find('.cell')
```

must be .box instead

```
$('.row').eq(indexI).find('.box').eq(indexJ).addClass('marvin');
```

Next time if the same thing happens (no errors on Browser Console), I suggest you to use the watch in Browser Developer Tools to check whether any selectors return the wrong items or not

Comment: why don't you copy my snippet as well? J

Comment: When I started typing the answer your anwer was not there. Simply same idea. Check the time